# JNLP to not start from cached jars if these not supported anymore by server?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

To avoid Webstart downloading about approx 100MB each time (required for checking jar equality), we employ the Webstart version protocol. A servlet generates the JNLP on the fly referring to the latest version Jars.

But when a specific version jar is not supported any longer, but it does reside in the webstart cache on a client machine, and they have an outdated JNLP file.
How can i block the JNLP file from running?

Is there an option to e.g. let Webstart check if the versioned Jar file actually still exist non the source location, and if not, then block execution?

Or should this be done programatically by the application itself, by obtaining version info from its jar-manifests, and sending it off to the server for a version check?

Comment: *"Or should this be done programatically by the application itself, by obtaining version info from its jar-manifests, and sending it off to the server for a version check?"*  This requirement would be best suited to the client app. taking direct control of downloads and updates.  That is done using the [`DownloadService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) of the JNLP API.